# Animated Jump thru it's children scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a good `jquery` or simple `js` plugin which, has vertical scroll bar and animated jumps thru it's children, as much as it was scrolled or dragged it's vertical scroll. It's an achievement to shorten my spent hours on this plugin.

I was google'ing but non of custom scroll bars which i find can do this.

Thanks in future. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) for free or flexcroll

Comment: Ok, how about the topic, animated jumping. I run thru all the examples and didn't find any animated jump, thru children, examples.

Comment: Jump thru children, not to scroll to offset.

Comment: So, I think you can try the api scrollToElement which has been described in this page http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html. It does support jquery animate object and you scroll to the children which is passed by a jQuery object, DOM node or jQuery selector string

Comment: I have created a demonstration, you could download it here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38306657/demo.zip